# URL Rewrite redirect one page to another similar page

Tags: url, redirect, url-rewriting

How do I redirect 2 similar URLs to 2 different URLs using URL Rewrite or web.config in IIS?

My 2 old URLs are:
http://example.com/used-2-3/
http://example.com/used-2-3-2/

My 2 new URLs are

http://example.com/eq/ex?action=283
http://example.com/eq/ex?action=435

So My web.config rewrite rules are like this, but it is not working

```
<rule name="Used Conveyors Redirect" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" negate="true" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="http://example.com/used-2-3/" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="http://www.example.com/used-2-3/" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/eq/ex?action=283" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Used Power Vans" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" negate="true" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="http://example.com/used-2-3-2/" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="http://www.example.com/used-2-3-2/" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/eq/ex?action=435" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>


It is not working because both old links redirect to the first new URL.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that in the rules you wrote there are the conditions logicalGrouping = "MatchAll" which means that ALL must match to be considered. I think you should use "MatchAny"...

Anyway why don't you use a simple rule like this?

```
<rule name="1stOLD" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="^used-2-3\/$" />
 <action type"redirect" url="/eq/ex?action=283" />
</rule>
<rule name="2ndOLD" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="^used-2-3-2\/$" />
 <action type"redirect" url="/eq/ex?action=435" />
</rule>
```

this 2 rule capture both http://www.example.com and http://example.com without specify it.
The "Match url" say:

```
^ : start with 
used-2-3 : matches the characters used-2-3 literally 
\/ : matches the character / literally 
$ : the end of the string
```